# asp.net flip string (swap words) between character

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, string

My scenario is i have a multiline textbox with multiple values e.g. below:

firstvalue = secondvalue

anothervalue = thisvalue

i am looking for a quick and easy scenario to flip the value e.g. below:

secondvalue = firstvalue

thisvalue = anothervalue

Can you help ?

Thanks

Comment: is this going to be done on the browser or on the server (use javascript or vb?)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] content = txtContent.Text.Split('\n');

    string ret = "";
    foreach (string s in content)
    {
        string[] parts = s.Split('=');
        if (parts.Count() == 2)
        {
            ret = ret + string.Format("{0} = {1}\n", parts[1].Trim(), parts[0].Trim());
        }
    }
    lblContentTransformed.Text = "<pre>" + ret + "</pre>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your multiline text box will always have text which is in the format you mentioned - "firstvalue = secondvalue" and "anothervalue = thisvalue". And considering that the text itself doesn't contain any "=". After that it is just string manipulation.

```
string multiline_text = textBox1.Text;
string[] split = multiline_text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

foreach (string a in split)
{          
      int equal = a.IndexOf("=");

      //result1 will now hold the first value of your string
      string result1 = a.Substring(0, equal);

      int result2_start = equal + 1;
      int result2_end = a.Length - equal -1 ;

      //result1 will now hold the second value of your string
      string result2 = a.Substring(result2_start, result2_end);

      //Concatenate both to get the reversed string
      string result = result2 + " = " + result1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Regex groups for this. Add two multi line textboxes to the page and a button. For the button's onclick event add:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<left>\w+)(\W+)(?<right>\w+)");
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(this.TextBox1.Text);
    while (matchResults.Success)
    {
        string left = matchResults.Groups["left"].Value;
        string right = matchResults.Groups["right"].Value;
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}{2}", right, left, Environment.NewLine);
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    }

    this.TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

It gives you a nice way to deal with the left and right hand sides that you are looking to swap, as an alternative to working with substrings and string lengths.